# Does <select> have a proper :active selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have an up arrow placed after my select box like so

```
.select-pokemon:after {
    content: "^";
}
```

However when the select box is showing its options and is selected I want the arrow to display an (x) icon. I have tried

```
.select-pokemon:active:after {
     content: "x";
}
```

But this only changes when I have directly clicked on the select box, when I've stopped clicking but the options are still displayed the content changes back to "^" is there a way to keep the icon "x" whilst the select box is showing all of its options?

Comment: I think you may need javascript/jquery to achieve what you're describing. For example, you could toggle an extra class on the div when the select box is clicked, eg class='select-pokemon hasX'

Comment: you actually cannot have **any** kind of `:after` / `:before` content in a `select` element because they are replaced elements. You must be using some kind of plugin that replaces the `select` elements with something else..

Comment: ...or is this currently browser specific?

Comment: You probably want `:focus`, not `:active`. What @Gabyaka said is still valid though; you should consider applying the generated content to an element _after_ the `select`, using the adjacent sibling combinator `~`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using JQuery is very easy and you can control the behavior desired.
A ^ is shown and when you click on the select a X is shown and when you click on an option the ^ come back:

Check here a fiddle demo with two more examples http://jsfiddle.net/manzapanza/hgpgtme5/

HTML:

```
<div class="after-b"></div>
<select name="bbb" class="select-pokemon-b">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>    
</select>
```

CSS:

```
.after-b{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 100px;
}
.after-b:after{
    content: "^";
}
.after-b.a:after{
    content: "x";
}
```

JS:

```
$('.select-pokemon-b').focus(function(){
    $('.after-b').toggleClass('a');
});
$('.select-pokemon-b').change(function(){
    $('.after-b').toggleClass('a');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use :focus.

```
.select-pokemon:focus:after {
     content: "x";
}
```

That should do the trick.